# Linux to Windows (OpenSSH) directory bindings

Tags: linux, windows, scp, openssh

I've got OpenSSH working on a windows machine and have been able to successfully connect from Linux to Windows and vice-versa.

I need to know how Linux paths are linked to windows while using scp.

For Example

1. `scp sampleFile arpit@windows_host:/tmp` -> sends the file to `C:\Windows\TEMP`
   *(found out that in `TMP` environment variable is set to `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP`)*
2. scp to `/opt` -> sends the file to `c:\Program Files\Git\opt`
3. scp to `/home/arpit/` -> sends the file to `c:\Documents and Settings\arpit\`

Any idea how these UNIX paths are linked to Windows?

Comment: Try asking your question on superuser, or a linux q&a site..

Comment: See how Cygwin [maps path names](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames).

Comment: Actually, I am not using Cygwin. This is an stand alone OpenSSH installation.